# Spark-submit job fails on yarn nodemanager with error Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, spark-submit, hortonworks-sandbox

I am running  spark-submit in yarn client mode. Yarn has been setup with HDP sandbox with kerberos enabled. HDP Sandbox is running on docker container on Mac host.
When spark submit is run from within the docker container of the sandbox, it’s runs successfully but when spark submit is run from the host machine it fails  immediately after ACCEPTED state with error:

```
19/07/28 00:41:21 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1564298049378_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/07/28 00:41:22 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1564298049378_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/07/28 00:41:23 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1564298049378_0008 (state: FAILED)
19/07/28 00:41:23 INFO yarn.Client:
client token: N/A
diagnostics: Application application_1564298049378_0008 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1564298049378_0008_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: (Client.java:1558)
... 37 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN,  KERBEROS]
```

I could not find any more information about the failure. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the resourcemanager log:

```
2019-07-28 22:39:04,654 INFO  resourcemanager.ClientRMService (ClientRMService.java:getNewApplicationId(341)) - Allocated new applicationId: 20
2019-07-28 22:39:10,982 INFO  capacity.CapacityScheduler (CapacityScheduler.java:checkAndGetApplicationPriority(2526)) - Application 'application_1564332457320_0020' is submitted without priority hence considering default queue/cluster priority: 0
2019-07-28 22:39:10,982 INFO  capacity.CapacityScheduler (CapacityScheduler.java:checkAndGetApplicationPriority(2547)) - Priority '0' is acceptable in queue : santosh for application: application_1564332457320_0020
2019-07-28 22:39:10,983 WARN  rmapp.RMAppImpl (RMAppImpl.java:(473)) - The specific max attempts: 0 for application: 20 is invalid, because it is out of the range [1, 2]. Use the global max attempts instead.
2019-07-28 22:39:10,983 INFO  collector.TimelineCollectorManager (TimelineCollectorManager.java:putIfAbsent(142)) - the collector for application_1564332457320_0020 was added
2019-07-28 22:39:10,984 INFO  resourcemanager.ClientRMService (ClientRMService.java:submitApplication(648)) - Application with id 20 submitted by user santosh
2019-07-28 22:39:10,984 INFO  security.DelegationTokenRenewer (DelegationTokenRenewer.java:handleAppSubmitEvent(458)) - application_1564332457320_0020 found existing hdfs token Kind: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: 192.168.50.1:8020, Ident: (token for santosh: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN owner=santosh@XXX.XX, renewer=yarn, realUser=, issueDate=1564353550169, maxDate=1564958350169, sequenceNumber=125, masterKeyId=20)
2019-07-28 22:39:11,011 INFO  security.DelegationTokenRenewer (DelegationTokenRenewer.java:renewToken(635)) - Renewed delegation-token= [Kind: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: 192.168.50.1:8020, Ident: (token for santosh: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN owner=santosh@XXX.XX, renewer=yarn, realUser=, issueDate=1564353550169, maxDate=1564958350169, sequenceNumber=125, masterKeyId=20);exp=1564439951007; apps=[application_1564332457320_0020]]
2019-07-28 22:39:11,011 INFO  security.DelegationTokenRenewer (DelegationTokenRenewer.java:setTimerForTokenRenewal(613)) - Renew Kind: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: 192.168.50.1:8020, Ident: (token for santosh: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN owner=santosh@XXX.XX, renewer=yarn, realUser=, issueDate=1564353550169, maxDate=1564958350169, sequenceNumber=125, masterKeyId=20);exp=1564439951007; apps=[application_1564332457320_0020] in 86399996 ms, appId = [application_1564332457320_0020]
2019-07-28 22:39:11,011 INFO  rmapp.RMAppImpl (RMAppImpl.java:transition(1259)) - Storing application with id application_1564332457320_0020
2019-07-28 22:39:11,012 INFO  rmapp.RMAppImpl (RMAppImpl.java:handle(912)) - application_1564332457320_0020 State change from NEW to NEW_SAVING on event = START
2019-07-28 22:39:11,012 INFO  recovery.RMStateStore (RMStateStore.java:transition(222)) - Storing info for app: application_1564332457320_0020
2019-07-28 22:39:11,022 INFO  rmapp.RMAppImpl (RMAppImpl.java:handle(912)) - application_1564332457320_0020 State change from NEW_SAVING to SUBMITTED on event = APP_NEW_SAVED
2019-07-28 22:39:11,022 INFO  capacity.ParentQueue (ParentQueue.java:addApplication(494)) - Application added - appId: application_1564332457320_0020 user: santosh leaf-queue of parent: root #applications: 1
2019-07-28 22:39:11,023 INFO  capacity.CapacityScheduler (CapacityScheduler.java:addApplication(990)) - Accepted application application_1564332457320_0020 from user: santosh, in queue: santosh
2019-07-28 22:39:11,023 INFO  rmapp.RMAppImpl (RMAppImpl.java:handle(912)) - application_1564332457320_0020 State change from SUBMITTED to ACCEPTED on event = APP_ACCEPTED
2019-07-28 22:39:11,023 INFO  resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService (ApplicationMasterService.java:registerAppAttempt(479)) - Registering app attempt : appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001
2019-07-28 22:39:11,024 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:handle(925)) - appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001 State change from NEW to SUBMITTED on event = START
2019-07-28 22:39:11,024 INFO  capacity.LeafQueue (LeafQueue.java:activateApplications(911)) - Application application_1564332457320_0020 from user: santosh activated in queue: santosh
2019-07-28 22:39:11,025 INFO  capacity.LeafQueue (LeafQueue.java:addApplicationAttempt(941)) - Application added - appId: application_1564332457320_0020 user: santosh, leaf-queue: santosh #user-pending-applications: 0 #user-active-applications: 1 #queue-pending-applications: 0 #queue-active-applications: 1
2019-07-28 22:39:11,025 INFO  capacity.CapacityScheduler (CapacityScheduler.java:addApplicationAttempt(1036)) - Added Application Attempt appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001 to scheduler from user santosh in queue santosh
2019-07-28 22:39:11,028 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:handle(925)) - appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001 State change from SUBMITTED to SCHEDULED on event = ATTEMPT_ADDED
2019-07-28 22:39:11,033 INFO  allocator.AbstractContainerAllocator (AbstractContainerAllocator.java:getCSAssignmentFromAllocateResult(129)) - assignedContainer application attempt=appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001 container=null queue=santosh clusterResource= type=OFF_SWITCH requestedPartition=
2019-07-28 22:39:11,034 INFO  rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl (RMContainerImpl.java:handle(490)) - container_e20_1564332457320_0020_01_000001 Container Transitioned from NEW to ALLOCATED
2019-07-28 22:39:11,035 INFO  fica.FiCaSchedulerNode (FiCaSchedulerNode.java:allocateContainer(169)) - Assigned container container_e20_1564332457320_0020_01_000001 of capacity  on host sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:45454, which has 1 containers,  used and  available after allocation
2019-07-28 22:39:11,038 INFO  security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM (NMTokenSecretManagerInRM.java:createAndGetNMToken(200)) - Sending NMToken for nodeId : sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:45454 for container : container_e20_1564332457320_0020_01_000001
2019-07-28 22:39:11,043 INFO  rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl (RMContainerImpl.java:handle(490)) - container_e20_1564332457320_0020_01_000001 Container Transitioned from ALLOCATED to ACQUIRED
2019-07-28 22:39:11,043 INFO  security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM (NMTokenSecretManagerInRM.java:clearNodeSetForAttempt(146)) - Clear node set for appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001
2019-07-28 22:39:11,044 INFO  capacity.ParentQueue (ParentQueue.java:apply(1332)) - assignedContainer queue=root usedCapacity=0.25 absoluteUsedCapacity=0.25 used= cluster=
2019-07-28 22:39:11,044 INFO  capacity.CapacityScheduler (CapacityScheduler.java:tryCommit(2890)) - Allocation proposal accepted
2019-07-28 22:39:11,044 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:storeAttempt(2213)) - Storing attempt: AppId: application_1564332457320_0020 AttemptId: appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001 MasterContainer: Container: [ContainerId: container_e20_1564332457320_0020_01_000001, AllocationRequestId: -1, Version: 0, NodeId: sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:45454, NodeHttpAddress: sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8042, Resource: , Priority: 0, Token: Token { kind: ContainerToken, service: 172.18.0.3:45454 }, ExecutionType: GUARANTEED, ]
2019-07-28 22:39:11,051 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:handle(925)) - appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001 State change from SCHEDULED to ALLOCATED_SAVING on event = CONTAINER_ALLOCATED
2019-07-28 22:39:11,057 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:handle(925)) - appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001 State change from ALLOCATED_SAVING to ALLOCATED on event = ATTEMPT_NEW_SAVED
2019-07-28 22:39:11,060 INFO  amlauncher.AMLauncher (AMLauncher.java:run(307)) - Launching masterappattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001
2019-07-28 22:39:11,068 INFO  amlauncher.AMLauncher (AMLauncher.java:launch(109)) - Setting up container Container: [ContainerId: container_e20_1564332457320_0020_01_000001, AllocationRequestId: -1, Version: 0, NodeId: sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:45454, NodeHttpAddress: sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8042, Resource: , Priority: 0, Token: Token { kind: ContainerToken, service: 172.18.0.3:45454 }, ExecutionType: GUARANTEED, ] for AM appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001
2019-07-28 22:39:11,069 INFO  security.AMRMTokenSecretManager (AMRMTokenSecretManager.java:createAndGetAMRMToken(195)) - Create AMRMToken for ApplicationAttempt: appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001
2019-07-28 22:39:11,069 INFO  security.AMRMTokenSecretManager (AMRMTokenSecretManager.java:createPassword(307)) - Creating password for appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001
2019-07-28 22:39:11,265 INFO  amlauncher.AMLauncher (AMLauncher.java:launch(130)) - Done launching container Container: [ContainerId: container_e20_1564332457320_0020_01_000001, AllocationRequestId: -1, Version: 0, NodeId: sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:45454, NodeHttpAddress: sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8042, Resource: , Priority: 0, Token: Token { kind: ContainerToken, service: 172.18.0.3:45454 }, ExecutionType: GUARANTEED, ] for AM appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001
2019-07-28 22:39:11,265 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:handle(925)) - appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001 State change from ALLOCATED to LAUNCHED on event = LAUNCHED
2019-07-28 22:39:11,852 INFO  resourcemanager.ResourceTrackerService (ResourceTrackerService.java:updateAppCollectorsMap(713)) - Update collector information for application application_1564332457320_0020 with new address: sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:35197 timestamp: 1564332457320, 36
2019-07-28 22:39:11,854 INFO  rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl (RMContainerImpl.java:handle(490)) - container_e20_1564332457320_0020_01_000001 Container Transitioned from ACQUIRED to RUNNING
2019-07-28 22:39:12,833 INFO  provider.BaseAuditHandler (BaseAuditHandler.java:logStatus(312)) - Audit Status Log: name=yarn.async.batch.hdfs, interval=01:11.979 minutes, events=162, succcessCount=162, totalEvents=17347, totalSuccessCount=17347
2019-07-28 22:39:12,834 INFO  destination.HDFSAuditDestination (HDFSAuditDestination.java:logJSON(179)) - Flushing HDFS audit. Event Size:1
2019-07-28 22:39:12,857 INFO  resourcemanager.ResourceTrackerService (ResourceTrackerService.java:updateAppCollectorsMap(713)) - Update collector information for application application_1564332457320_0020 with new address: sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:35197 timestamp: 1564332457320, 37
2019-07-28 22:39:14,054 INFO  rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl (RMContainerImpl.java:handle(490)) - container_e20_1564332457320_0020_01_000001 Container Transitioned from RUNNING to COMPLETED
2019-07-28 22:39:14,055 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:rememberTargetTransitionsAndStoreState(1412)) - Updating application attempt appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001 with final state: FAILED, and exit status: -1000
2019-07-28 22:39:14,055 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:handle(925)) - appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001 State change from LAUNCHED to FINAL_SAVING on event = CONTAINER_FINISHED
2019-07-28 22:39:14,066 INFO  resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService (ApplicationMasterService.java:unregisterAttempt(496)) - Unregistering app attempt : appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001
2019-07-28 22:39:14,066 INFO  security.AMRMTokenSecretManager (AMRMTokenSecretManager.java:applicationMasterFinished(124)) - Application finished, removing password for appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001
2019-07-28 22:39:14,066 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:handle(925)) - appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001 State change from FINAL_SAVING to FAILED on event = ATTEMPT_UPDATE_SAVED
2019-07-28 22:39:14,067 INFO  rmapp.RMAppImpl (RMAppImpl.java:transition(1538)) - The number of failed attempts is 1. The max attempts is 2
2019-07-28 22:39:14,067 INFO  resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService (ApplicationMasterService.java:registerAppAttempt(479)) - Registering app attempt : appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002
2019-07-28 22:39:14,067 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:handle(925)) - appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002 State change from NEW to SUBMITTED on event = START
2019-07-28 22:39:14,067 INFO  capacity.CapacityScheduler (CapacityScheduler.java:doneApplicationAttempt(1085)) - Application Attempt appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000001 is done. finalState=FAILED
2019-07-28 22:39:14,067 INFO  scheduler.AppSchedulingInfo (AppSchedulingInfo.java:clearRequests(159)) - Application application_1564332457320_0020 requests cleared
2019-07-28 22:39:14,067 INFO  capacity.LeafQueue (LeafQueue.java:removeApplicationAttempt(1003)) - Application removed - appId: application_1564332457320_0020 user: santosh queue: santosh #user-pending-applications: 0 #user-active-applications: 0 #queue-pending-applications: 0 #queue-active-applications: 0
2019-07-28 22:39:14,068 INFO  capacity.LeafQueue (LeafQueue.java:activateApplications(911)) - Application application_1564332457320_0020 from user: santosh activated in queue: santosh
2019-07-28 22:39:14,068 INFO  capacity.LeafQueue (LeafQueue.java:addApplicationAttempt(941)) - Application added - appId: application_1564332457320_0020 user: santosh, leaf-queue: santosh #user-pending-applications: 0 #user-active-applications: 1 #queue-pending-applications: 0 #queue-active-applications: 1
2019-07-28 22:39:14,068 INFO  capacity.CapacityScheduler (CapacityScheduler.java:addApplicationAttempt(1036)) - Added Application Attempt appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002 to scheduler from user santosh in queue santosh
2019-07-28 22:39:14,068 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:handle(925)) - appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002 State change from SUBMITTED to SCHEDULED on event = ATTEMPT_ADDED
2019-07-28 22:39:14,074 INFO  allocator.AbstractContainerAllocator (AbstractContainerAllocator.java:getCSAssignmentFromAllocateResult(129)) - assignedContainer application attempt=appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002 container=null queue=santosh clusterResource= type=OFF_SWITCH requestedPartition=
2019-07-28 22:39:14,074 INFO  rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl (RMContainerImpl.java:handle(490)) - container_e20_1564332457320_0020_02_000001 Container Transitioned from NEW to ALLOCATED
2019-07-28 22:39:14,075 INFO  fica.FiCaSchedulerNode (FiCaSchedulerNode.java:allocateContainer(169)) - Assigned container container_e20_1564332457320_0020_02_000001 of capacity  on host sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:45454, which has 1 containers,  used and  available after allocation
2019-07-28 22:39:14,075 INFO  security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM (NMTokenSecretManagerInRM.java:createAndGetNMToken(200)) - Sending NMToken for nodeId : sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:45454 for container : container_e20_1564332457320_0020_02_000001
2019-07-28 22:39:14,076 INFO  rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl (RMContainerImpl.java:handle(490)) - container_e20_1564332457320_0020_02_000001 Container Transitioned from ALLOCATED to ACQUIRED
2019-07-28 22:39:14,076 INFO  security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM (NMTokenSecretManagerInRM.java:clearNodeSetForAttempt(146)) - Clear node set for appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002
2019-07-28 22:39:14,076 INFO  capacity.ParentQueue (ParentQueue.java:apply(1332)) - assignedContainer queue=root usedCapacity=0.25 absoluteUsedCapacity=0.25 used= cluster=
2019-07-28 22:39:14,076 INFO  capacity.CapacityScheduler (CapacityScheduler.java:tryCommit(2890)) - Allocation proposal accepted
2019-07-28 22:39:14,076 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:storeAttempt(2213)) - Storing attempt: AppId: application_1564332457320_0020 AttemptId: appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002 MasterContainer: Container: [ContainerId: container_e20_1564332457320_0020_02_000001, AllocationRequestId: -1, Version: 0, NodeId: sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:45454, NodeHttpAddress: sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8042, Resource: , Priority: 0, Token: Token { kind: ContainerToken, service: 172.18.0.3:45454 }, ExecutionType: GUARANTEED, ]
2019-07-28 22:39:14,077 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:handle(925)) - appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002 State change from SCHEDULED to ALLOCATED_SAVING on event = CONTAINER_ALLOCATED
2019-07-28 22:39:14,088 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:handle(925)) - appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002 State change from ALLOCATED_SAVING to ALLOCATED on event = ATTEMPT_NEW_SAVED
2019-07-28 22:39:14,089 INFO  amlauncher.AMLauncher (AMLauncher.java:run(307)) - Launching masterappattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002
2019-07-28 22:39:14,091 INFO  amlauncher.AMLauncher (AMLauncher.java:launch(109)) - Setting up container Container: [ContainerId: container_e20_1564332457320_0020_02_000001, AllocationRequestId: -1, Version: 0, NodeId: sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:45454, NodeHttpAddress: sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8042, Resource: , Priority: 0, Token: Token { kind: ContainerToken, service: 172.18.0.3:45454 }, ExecutionType: GUARANTEED, ] for AM appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002
2019-07-28 22:39:14,092 INFO  security.AMRMTokenSecretManager (AMRMTokenSecretManager.java:createAndGetAMRMToken(195)) - Create AMRMToken for ApplicationAttempt: appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002
2019-07-28 22:39:14,092 INFO  security.AMRMTokenSecretManager (AMRMTokenSecretManager.java:createPassword(307)) - Creating password for appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002
2019-07-28 22:39:14,110 INFO  amlauncher.AMLauncher (AMLauncher.java:launch(130)) - Done launching container Container: [ContainerId: container_e20_1564332457320_0020_02_000001, AllocationRequestId: -1, Version: 0, NodeId: sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:45454, NodeHttpAddress: sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8042, Resource: , Priority: 0, Token: Token { kind: ContainerToken, service: 172.18.0.3:45454 }, ExecutionType: GUARANTEED, ] for AM appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002
2019-07-28 22:39:14,110 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:handle(925)) - appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002 State change from ALLOCATED to LAUNCHED on event = LAUNCHED
2019-07-28 22:39:15,056 INFO  rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl (RMContainerImpl.java:handle(490)) - container_e20_1564332457320_0020_02_000001 Container Transitioned from ACQUIRED to RUNNING
2019-07-28 22:39:16,752 INFO  rmcontainer.RMContainerImpl (RMContainerImpl.java:handle(490)) - container_e20_1564332457320_0020_02_000001 Container Transitioned from RUNNING to COMPLETED
2019-07-28 22:39:16,755 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:rememberTargetTransitionsAndStoreState(1412)) - Updating application attempt appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002 with final state: FAILED, and exit status: -1000
2019-07-28 22:39:16,755 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:handle(925)) - appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002 State change from LAUNCHED to FINAL_SAVING on event = CONTAINER_FINISHED
2019-07-28 22:39:16,899 INFO  resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService (ApplicationMasterService.java:unregisterAttempt(496)) - Unregistering app attempt : appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002
2019-07-28 22:39:16,900 INFO  security.AMRMTokenSecretManager (AMRMTokenSecretManager.java:applicationMasterFinished(124)) - Application finished, removing password for appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002
2019-07-28 22:39:16,900 INFO  attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl (RMAppAttemptImpl.java:handle(925)) - appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002 State change from FINAL_SAVING to FAILED on event = ATTEMPT_UPDATE_SAVED
2019-07-28 22:39:16,900 INFO  rmapp.RMAppImpl (RMAppImpl.java:transition(1538)) - The number of failed attempts is 2. The max attempts is 2
2019-07-28 22:39:16,900 INFO  rmapp.RMAppImpl (RMAppImpl.java:rememberTargetTransitionsAndStoreState(1278)) - Updating application application_1564332457320_0020 with final state: FAILED
2019-07-28 22:39:16,900 INFO  rmapp.RMAppImpl (RMAppImpl.java:handle(912)) - application_1564332457320_0020 State change from ACCEPTED to FINAL_SAVING on event = ATTEMPT_FAILED
2019-07-28 22:39:16,900 INFO  recovery.RMStateStore (RMStateStore.java:transition(260)) - Updating info for app: application_1564332457320_0020
2019-07-28 22:39:16,900 INFO  capacity.CapacityScheduler (CapacityScheduler.java:doneApplicationAttempt(1085)) - Application Attempt appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002 is done. finalState=FAILED
2019-07-28 22:39:16,901 INFO  scheduler.AppSchedulingInfo (AppSchedulingInfo.java:clearRequests(159)) - Application application_1564332457320_0020 requests cleared
2019-07-28 22:39:16,901 INFO  capacity.LeafQueue (LeafQueue.java:removeApplicationAttempt(1003)) - Application removed - appId: application_1564332457320_0020 user: santosh queue: santosh #user-pending-applications: 0 #user-active-applications: 0 #queue-pending-applications: 0 #queue-active-applications: 0
2019-07-28 22:39:16,916 INFO  rmapp.RMAppImpl (RMAppImpl.java:transition(1197)) - Application application_1564332457320_0020 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1564332457320_0020_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: (Client.java:1558)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1389)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.selectSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:173)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2300(Client.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:796)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:796)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
```

Comment: You have to dig out the YARN logs for that failed AM _(ApplicationMaster)_ YARN container, to find the root cause. But since the AM has failed, there was no log aggregation to HDFS, so you have to search the appropriate Docker container for the "temp YARN logs" files for the YARN container - before it is purged.

Comment: For some context about the way Spark handles Hadoop "auth tokens" for its executors, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44290544/5162372 (ignore the stuff that is specific to HBase)

Comment: BTW, I guess you did some research and already read that post, riight...? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755479/client-cannot-authenticate-viatoken-kerberos?rq=1

Comment: @Samson Scharfrichter  The temp yarn container log :  `[ContainerLocalizer Downloader] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]` . I read the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755479/client-cannot-authenticate-viatoken-kerberos?rq=1 before posting the question. I will check the other post you shared. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: hi, i face the some probleme on a CDH 6.3.3. any one find the solution ?